# sqlplus command returns help page when executed from crontab in linux

Tags: shell, cron, sqlplus

sqlplus command when executed from crontab calling a shell script displays help page as output

didnt get any help to solve this

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DB_CURRENT_SCHEMA/$DB_PASSWD@$ORACLE_SID << EOF > /ipomapp/TAPESTRY/queue_count/queue_count.out
select count(*),Q_name from tap_infce.interface_xml_queue having count(*) > 500 group by Q_name;
EOF
```

it should display queue count, but it prints sqlplus help page

Comment: $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DB_CURRENT_SCHEMA/$DB_PASSWD@$ORACLE_SID << EOF > /ipomapp/TAPESTRY/queue_count/queue_count.out
select count(*),Q_name from tap_infce.interface_xml_queue having count(*) > 500 group by Q_name;
EOF

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question itself, don't use the comment section for that

Comment: added the script too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a here-doc, you could try saving your sql to a variable, then piping that variable to sqlplus. I'm not familiar with your query, so if it's flawed, it'll need to be fixed as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

sql="> /ipomapp/TAPESTRY/queue_count/queue_count.out select count(),Q_name from tap_infce.interface_xml_queue having count() > 500 group by Q_name;"

echo "$sql" | $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DB_CURRENT_SCHEMA/$DB_PASSWD@$ORACLE_SID
```